# Why am I getting "Our system has identified this post as possible spam" in review audits?

Tags: support, review-queues, review-audits, spam

Today I noticed a strange behavior when reviewing first posts and late answers. Although I would have flagged them by default, the system told me:

> Our system has identified this post as possible spam; please review carefully

But **both of them were review audits!**

Variation for Suggested Edits:

> Our system has identified this edit as possible spam; please review carefully

This happened [two](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/5436169) [times](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/5436125) today, shortly behind another.

[image: Our system has identified this post as possible spam]

I'm just wondering: Where is the challenge when the expected review audit result is displayed?

Comment: It's probably not a bug.  It's definitely a reminder to cast a critical eye on answers like this, that are nothing more than a link to an outside resource.

Comment: The system triggers on text and a link without any codeblock

Comment: I've only ever seen it on audits. Granted, I'm only at about 200 reviews.

Comment: Why should reviewing be a challenge? If a computer can make something easier for you and the performance cost, etc. aren't too much because of the extra text & processing, why not let it?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

This was actually a feature designed to help keep out spam from the Stack Exchange network. It tries to tell you "Hey, you should pay *extra* attention to this review, because it might just be spam."

There's more information provided about this system in [Tim Post's answer on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/216400/237685).

Now, is this message supposed to show up on audits? According to [another one of Tim Post's answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/216787/237685), yes, it is:

> The spam notification is completely unaware of audits, and audits are completely unaware of the spam notifications (however, audits do
>   know when something was rejected as spam, that's why it chose the edit
>   as an audit). The actual notification that tells you that the message
>   was identified as spam comes from something completely different.
>
> What happened is, the post was rejected so recently that the origin
>   was still being tracked by the spam filters, which is why you got that
>   message. In effect, this *should* cause anyone to slow down and take a
>   good look (audit or not) before suggesting action.
>
> **However, as audits should represent the 'real deal' as much as possible, I don't see a reason to not show the extra notification when you happen on something in an audit that originated from something we're tracking as abusive.**

Comment: Thanks for the reference! I think I missed up the split of meta again I guess and didn't properly search for it on the other meta :/

Comment: @ConcurrentHashMap The mSO/mSE split has made searching annoying, you search on mSE and find out it was asked on mSO, or vice versa.. . :/

Comment: The strange thing about that is every time I get that message when reviewing, it's on a review audit where the post is actually high quality. [And apparently, I'm not the only one for whom it's like that.](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/328111/why-did-the-system-identify-this-audit-as-possible-spam)

Comment: @DonaldDuck I usually get that on low quality, but I just got it on a very good _question_ in the NAA/VLQ queue (7 votes, and it's a question so it _has_ to be an audit because questions don't belong to this queue). Strange indeed.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre According to the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/161391/349538), questions can actually be in the Low Quality Posts Queue without being audits (I assume that happens if they're flagged as Very Low Quality), but that's very rare and personally the only questions I've seen in that queue were audits.