# How to handle VLQQ posts that are identified as spam

Tags: discussion, review-queues, low-quality-posts

Today, I encountered [this entry](https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/5452004) in the Very Low Quality Queue. For future reference: This question only consists of code, with some random comments in it that may or may not resemble some kind of chaotic question. It says the system identified it as spam, but I can't find the spammy nature of this post. It is a very bad question though, so closing it as such is appropriate. Is there anything else I should do?

Besides that, if such a question is actually spam, should I flag the question as well? The queue doesn't allow me to flag the post in the queue, but I could click through to the actual question to do that.

---

Edit: I am aware of [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267355/why-am-i-getting-our-system-has-identified-this-post-as-possible-spam-in-revie), but that question is about review audits and the confusion why 'StackOverflow would give a hint to pay attention with that message on review audits'. Besides that this question isn't about review audits and therefore there is no such confusion, the only action that really matters on a review audit is what button you click. In this case I was wondering if I should do additional actions inside or outside the queue that are irrelevant for review audits.

Comment: I can't see anything there that would identify this question as spam (with none of the earlier versions either).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why am I getting "Our system has identified this post as possible spam" in review audits?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267355/why-am-i-getting-our-system-has-identified-this-post-as-possible-spam-in-revie)

Comment: @iStimple I have seen that question, but this isn't an audit. It doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @Sumurai8 http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/194495/165773

Comment: @gnat Fine, I have now edited my question to include why this is not the same as the duplicate. I find it rather pointless though to double the question size just to cater for people that didn't bother reading.

Comment: @Sumurai8 in your case it was probably worth it - at least to me it was only your explanation of the difference that made me change my mind from voting to close to leave open in review queue. By the way feel free to ping me if question [bandwagons into closure](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/144557/165773) despite the explanation - I'll vote reopen

Answer (score 19, accepted):

> Our system has identified this post as possible spam; **please review carefully**

That's exactly what you should do - review carefully. Spam detection is based on heuristics, and can't be 100% accurate. So something with more intricate pattern matching capabilities, highly tuned heuristics and critical reasoning abilities<sup>*</sup>, is required. Make sure you're focused when you're dealing with a post that was identified as potential spam:

- It could indeed be spam, in which case you should absolutely flag it as such. This will help get rid of it as fast as possible, and provide feedback to the spam detection machinery, hopefully making it more accurate.
- It could be a false positive. In that case, don't flag it as spam (of course) but treat it as any other review. The fact that the post doesn't get deleted as spam should also provide feedback to the spam hunting system, hopefully reducing the false-positives in the long run.

So be careful and wield the spam hammer wisely.

And remember, if you're unsure, there's the skip button.

<sub><sup>*</sup>Human brains, if engaged in the activity and unhindered (or possibly enhanced) by psychotropic substances are capable of this. This is just an example though. Other forms exist or may arise.</sub>

Comment: I feel slightly offended that you assume I have human brains. Thanks for the response though.

Comment: @Sumurai8 if you happen to not have a human brain or equivalent, please refrain from using the review queue. The fact that you are capable of written english (both comprehension and generation) seems to indicate that you seem to have a human brain, however.

Comment: @JanDvorak My brain is that of a unicorn, a species that is far beyond of what humans are capable of. Sadly, it doesn't interact well with the human body, so I am not quite capable of utilizing all it's capabilities... yet.

Comment: @JanDvorak why the specieism? What do you have against our non-human members? What do you have against our non-organic members even?

Comment: Human brains are based on heuristics

Comment: @Sumurai8: amended. Hopefully less human-centered now, sorry about that.

Comment: @Mat thanks for editing your answer. I also felt offended. As you can imagine my brain is 100% reindeer's brain (Elmo is a popular name for a reindeer).