# Good answer as negative audit

Tags: discussion, review-audits, disputed-review-audits, specific-audit

Here a perfectly valid answer explaining the difference between polling and long-polling quite well, got deleted and flagged as spam/offensive:

https://stackoverflow.com/review/low-quality-posts/24329124

Furthermore, it became a review audit, which I promptly failed ;)
What happened here?

Edit: Screenshot

> [image: Screenshot]

Original question:

[polling vs long polling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18099798/polling-vs-long-polling)

Edit: Indeed, the question is a duplicate of this question: [Why did I fail on the audit review?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/390218) . However, this question was also closed as a duplicate, but the duplicates mentioned *there* do not at all discuss the root cause of this issue. For that reason, I would prefer to not close this question.

Especially this duplicate of the referenced question: [How to handle VLQQ posts that are identified as spam](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/267600/how-to-handle-vlqq-posts-that-are-identified-as-spam) clearly states what to do, and what I have done. So please, codify a correct procedure for doing such reviews, or even better, do not use such thing as audits. Just out of curiosity: How many people have failed/passed it?

Furthermore, I doubt that the "identified as spam" notice appeared in my case (can't look it up retrospectively).

Comment: This audit has been mentioned a few days ago. As far as I remember this answer was coming from a spam account. Here: [Why did I fail on the audit review?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/390218)

Comment: There's a link in the answer - I'm not 10k so I can't see the URL. It's plausible the answer was deleted as spam: plagiarised text with a spam link is a known spam pattern.

Comment: @WaiHaLee: Just a link to general explanation text for (long) polling: https://www.ably.io/concepts/long-polling . Doesn't look plagiarized from there

Comment: @Tom Yes, indeed. Thanks for looking that up. However, I am quite sure, that there was no "identified as spam" message in my case. And even if it were: If the post is clearly not spam or plagiarized, there should be no issue.

Comment: Looks like the post was deleted as spam since the user account was destroyed as well. There was likely a connection between the username and the website, or the user was posting multiple answers with links to ably.io.

Comment: Related (not duplicate): [Should this (partial) answer be an audit in the Low Quality Posts Review Queue?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/388914/1364007). [The answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/388919/1364007) says "All negative-scored posts of a user being spam-deleted, is a side-effect of a user deleted for spam.".

Comment: We need a mod to remove this from the queues. Too many people are being tripped up on it, and it's definitely not obvious that it's spam.

Comment: You're the [4th person](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56187643/timeline) to fail this particular audit.

Comment: @CertainPerformance Thanks, I never find these links... proves at least, that the "Our system has identified this post as possible spam; please review carefully" string indeed wasn't present in my audit, as compared to the one in the duplicate message. Not that it makes much difference, however...

Comment: @JL2210 unfortunately mods don't have the ability to "un-audit" posts, they can only remove the triggering condition if the situation allows it. In this case the condition is a post being deleted because the author was a spammer... I don't see that being possible to resolve.