# What about this post was wrong (that I didn't notice?)

Tags: support, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

There was a [Python question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65585639/eigenvalues-in-python-a-bug) I was reviewing while doing the triage. Before I did anything, they explained:

> Our system has identified this post as possible spam; please review carefully

Okay, I knew it could probably be an audit. I reviewed it, and it seemed like a math question. But, it seemed more like a bug in Python, so I let that much pass. I got to one part,

> Here are my questions:

And then 4 questions. So keeping that in mind, I scrolled down farther. I saw "reactions" to comments further down in the post with lots of information. I had no idea what he was talking about (eigenvalues? eigenvectors? hermitian matrices?) but I had seen Python code. I chose to flag for "needs more focus." I then got the message that I didn't pass [the audit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/28236228). No explanation as to what the correct option was. The message also said "keeping in mind the guidance above," with no guidance except that I was wrong.

What should I have chosen instead?

[image: Here's the message I got after I chose my option1]

Comment: Relevant: [Why am I getting “Our system has identified this post as possible spam” in review audits?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/267355/11682469)

Comment: Also: [I do not understand why I failed this audit](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303795/i-do-not-understand-why-i-failed-this-audit)

Comment: @yivi so these audits are wrong? Should I just deal with it?

Comment: _Some_ audits are wrong. The important bit is that audits are chosen automatically. Failing a bad audit now and then shouldn't be a problem, but you could always act on the post outside of the queue. Downvotes or close votes would eventually remove the question from the audit pool. Note that I haven't really read this question so I don't know if this particular one is bad or not. It's too long, got bored.

Comment: @yivi thanks! I did see that one of my reviews was wrong, but that was a few months ago. I guess I'll just wait two days and not worry about it.

Comment: I had a look at the post. For me, it looks quite interesting, but rather difficult (and I am used to such eigenvalues problems, but not in python). It is a programming issue: we cannot always expect a perfect answer of libraries, and some experience is needed for example to select the best algorithm (i.e. the best function) among those proposed by a given library. In short, the audit is not wrong, it seems a good post, but a really difficult audit.

Comment: Pro tip: click the link on the right on a review and compare the post score to what's presented to you in the review. If it's different, you are likely in an audit.

Comment: @WaiHaLee So if I skip the audit, will I be presented with another audit or a normal review?

Comment: @Damien Would it have been better for me to skip it?

Comment: You can skip the audit - it's not guaranteed the next review will be an audit. Also you can pass the audit by selecting "looks okay" (in this case).

Comment: I too would have chosen "Needs more focus". While the question seems interesting, it still ticks basically all flags for the close reason. There are several assumptions and questions that need addressing. The code and data dumps are *huge*. The question keeps on growing with discussion. And some more...

Comment: @Rojo Certainly better to skip if you are not sure. That said, I stopped participating in triage: too difficult. I was banned several times. Now, I only flag (or not) questions that I met in the normal process of looking at questions corresponding to my preferred tags.

Comment: This question is such an edge case IMO; leaving it open seems correct and closing it seems correct. Should definitely not be taken as an audit.